I can not find nexus.adaptavist.com
Where is https://nexus.adaptavist.com?
PS > curl https://nexus.adaptavist.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nexus.adaptavist.com
I need download scriptrunner, but it haven't.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.onresolve.scriptrunner.platform/shared/6.34.0-RC1

Adaptavist has recently moved Nexus from nexus.ataptavist.com to nexus.adaptavist.net domain.
More details are here:
https://bitbucket.org/adaptavistlabs/scriptrunner-samples/commits/aaf609a54b1f014b36768800e765aa120fbf95d9
Now repository in pom.xml should be like this:
<repository>
  <id>adaptavist-external</id>
  <url>https://nexus.adaptavist.net/content/repositories/external</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
  </releases>
</repository>

